# N x N matrix has N nonzero eigenvalues but has the zero-vector as eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I’m trying to diagonalize the following matrix:
$$ A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
  1&3\\
  4&2
\end{matrix}
\right] $$

I’ve found the eigenvalues to be:
$$ \lambda = 2$$
$$ \lambda = 1$$

For $\text{$\lambda=2$}$, the eigenvector I have is
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
3\\
1
\end{matrix}
 \right]$$

But for $\text{$\lambda=1$}$, I am getting an eigenvector of:
 $$\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
0
\end{matrix}
 \right]$$

Are my eigenvalues wrong or does this just mean that I can’t diagonalize the matrix $A$?

Comment: The eigenvalues are $5$ and  $-2$. Check your work again. In particular, have you got the characteristic polynomial wrong? It should be $(x-1)(x-2) - 3 \times 4  = 0$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг nice catch! I forgot to include the `-12` in the characteristic equation. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you managed to find the eigenvectors as well.